# Why acquiring a locked lock is slower when using JDK21 compared to JDK11

Tags: java, performance, jmh, java-21, openjdk-21

While optimizing some locking stuff, I used a JMH benchmark to see how much does locking a locked ReentrantLock costs compared to just locking it once. I was surprised when I saw that jdk11 performed better than jdk21..It would be really nice to understand why and whether my benchmark correct after all.

I also added benchmark with synchronised block and without any locking at all. As expected, synchronised block is optimized and performs almost as the lock-free one and there is no degradation between different jdk versions.

```
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 10, time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Fork(1)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
public class LockNoLockBenchmark {
  int counter;

  ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();


  @Benchmark
  public void noLock() {
    ++counter;
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void syncLock() {
    synchronized (new Object()) {
      ++counter;
    }
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void lockUnlock() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
      ++counter;
    } finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void lockLockUnlockUnlock() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
      lock.lock();
      try {
        ++counter;
      } finally {
        lock.unlock();
      }
    } finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }
}
```

Run on Intel Rocket Lake (Core i9) 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-12950HX 12 cores 64Gb RAM

1. JDK 21

```
openjdk 21.0.2 2024-01-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.2+13-58)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.2+13-58, mixed mode, sharing)

Benchmark                                 Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
LockNoLockBenchmark.lockLockUnlockUnlock  avgt   10  27.457 ± 0.876  ns/op
LockNoLockBenchmark.lockUnlock            avgt   10  11.409 ± 0.256  ns/op
LockNoLockBenchmark.noLock                avgt   10   0.280 ± 0.010  ns/op
LockNoLockBenchmark.syncLock              avgt   10   0.280 ± 0.008  ns/op
```

2. JDK 11

```
openjdk 11.0.21 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.21+9-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.21+9-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04, mixed mode, sharing)

Benchmark                                 Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
LockNoLockBenchmark.lockLockUnlockUnlock  avgt   10  22.414 ± 1.366  ns/op
LockNoLockBenchmark.lockUnlock            avgt   10  11.690 ± 0.407  ns/op
LockNoLockBenchmark.noLock                avgt   10   0.283 ± 0.021  ns/op
LockNoLockBenchmark.syncLock              avgt   10   0.289 ± 0.012  ns/op
```

I'd expect no degradation in performance for this case with JDK21.
I am also interested what are some ways to optimize the code when I need to acquire a locked lock.
Thank you.

Comment: "I'd expect no degradation in performance for this case with JDK21"  Explain

Comment: First two places to check for answer would be JDK source code and generated bytecode. However, AFAIK the actual locking happens in native code, so that would also be worth looking at. As you can see newer is not always better, that's wht many people (including me) stick with older JDK versions.

Comment: @possum The statement is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: @possum not sure what to explain here, I don't expect my code to work slower with a newer JDK version..

Comment: @jurez most of time we have better performance with newer versions and I am not even talking about new features which can improve things significantly (e.g. virtual threads)

Comment: @alexid I don't think "because you feel like it shouldn't" is valid reasoning.  Do you believe the JDK maintainers are obligated to only improve performance?

Comment: @possum where did I say that "I feel like it" ? from what I know from talks of JDK perf engineers like Shipilev, they monitor the performance carefully and allow degradataion when there is a reason for that. that's why I am asking my question here..

Comment: @alexid Newer JVM versions usually need more memory, and that trivially can explain why sticking with an old version is better for performance reasons. JVMs updates usually also mess with the GC and that, too, can easily explain why locking in JVM21 is slightly 'heavier' than in JVM11.

Comment: "I am also interested what are some ways to optimize the code when I need to acquire a locked lock." this seems to be asking for opinions. Recommendations and opinion-based questions are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) for Stackoverflow.

Comment: It could be that you see the effects of [JEP 374: Deprecate and Disable Biased Locking](https://openjdk.org/jeps/374)

Comment: @ThomasKläger I tried to enable it via -XX:+UseBiasedLocking and used jdk17, but it didn't change the result :(

Comment: @rzwitserloot I'd be interested to see these benchmarks as it contradicts what Oracle and most of articles I saw tell, like this one for example : https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2021/09/15/HowMuchFasterIsJava17.html

Comment: I don’t do a lot of benchmarking, so I’m not sure I’m reading the output correctly.  It appears to say that the lockLockUnlockUnlock method takes 5 nanoseconds longer.  Is this really a concern for you?  I’m curious what sort of programs would be noticeably impacted by this.

Comment: @VGR we can look at it from the other side, 5 ns difference is more than 20% difference per operation. anyway, my question comes from curiosity and is a side-effect of my work on locking optimization, but it's not a production code :)

Comment: @aled I don't see how that is asking for an opinion. Unless every question asking for ways to do something is an opinion, in which case all questions should be off topic.

Comment: The `syncLock` benchmark is likely not measuring locking. You are creating a new non-escaping object, and the JIT can determine no locking is needed for that. If you want to measure the locking, stick the lock object in an instance field (like the `counter` you have).

Comment: @JornVernee yes, my intention was to see if the lock is eliminated as in the same benchmark Shipilev(the author of JMH) wrote https://shipilev.net/jvm/anatomy-quarks/19-lock-elision/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JDK 14, there was a massive rewrite of `java.util.concurrent` internals in the context of [JDK-8229442](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8229442). The goal was to improve overall performance of concurrent primitives and prepare the implementation for virtual threads.

However, as it often happens, improvements in one scenario are accompanied by a regression in another.

In JDK 11, [the code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11u/blob/54d1857208c45128bec2f2450d442d0e04d24dca/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.java#L126-L143) for recursive locking looks as follows. It has a fast path for checking if the lock is owned by the current thread. Note that there is no atomic `compareAndSet` operation on this path.

```
final boolean nonfairTryAcquire(int acquires) {
    final Thread current = Thread.currentThread();
    int c = getState();
    if (c == 0) {
        if (compareAndSetState(0, acquires)) {
            setExclusiveOwnerThread(current);
            return true;
        }
    }
    else if (current == getExclusiveOwnerThread()) {
        int nextc = c + acquires;
        if (nextc < 0) // overflow
            throw new Error("Maximum lock count exceeded");
        setState(nextc);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In JDK 21, [the code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk21u/blob/57956950c9c5b25523e54666a01171fba45d7e29/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.java#L223-L236) looks a bit differently. `initialTryLock` always executes `compareAndSetState`, whether the lock is recursive or not, and that's where the performance difference comes from.

```
final boolean initialTryLock() {
    Thread current = Thread.currentThread();
    if (compareAndSetState(0, 1)) { // first attempt is unguarded
        setExclusiveOwnerThread(current);
        return true;
    } else if (getExclusiveOwnerThread() == current) {
        int c = getState() + 1;
        if (c < 0) // overflow
            throw new Error("Maximum lock count exceeded");
        setState(c);
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

The aforementioned refactoring [already caused](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8317960) a performance regression earlier, which was later fixed. If your question arose from a real issue in production, you're welcome to submit a bug report.

As a side notice, your `syncLock()` benchmark does not actually measure performance of `synchronized`, since locking on a local non-escaped object is a no-op, and JIT compiler happily eliminates unnecessary locking altogether.

Comment: Big thanks Andrei! Very helpful.
Yes, I used syncLock to see if it is eliminated as expected, so it is expected behavior so to say.